# geofencing dwell event never received when adding geofence with device within the radius

Tags: android, android-location, android-geofence, android-googleapiclient

I made a simple test app, setup location and geofencing monitoring using  `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient` and `LocationServices.getGeofencingClient`.

I added a geofence using just the dwell transition notification and initial trigger, with the right position and radius such that I was expecting the 'dwell' event very soon after adding the geofence:

```
geofenceBuilder.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL);
...
builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
```

In device log I noticed several of these two, each time position was obtained:

[image]

The geofencing pending intent was never triggered. The device was on my desk.

I didn't understand what's going on. I even tried to switched to Google Maps and switched back to the app, it didn't do anything. The device is clearly not in any deep sleep since I am using it. So what's in deep sleep? I am guessing some geofencing component in Google Play Services? But the location is being queried constantly by the app, so why doesn't the Google Play Services geofencing sees I am inside the location and send the 'dwell' event?

After I moved around the house with the device, the two log entries didn't appear anymore and I got the geofencing dwell event!

<s>My conclusion is if device\Android component is in this "sleep" mode when a geofence is being set, I don't think the geofencing events won't fire, at least not the 'dwell' per my tests, as I am writing this I haven't tested to see if 'enter' is called.</s>

What is this "deep sleep mode" and "GeofencerStateMachine" ? Is it from Android Google Play services? How does it work? What's the reason I didn't get the 'dwell' event?

**On another device (Samsung Galaxy) I see same behavior, the dwell event is not received, but there's no similar log entry with 'deep sleep' and moving the device around doesn't make it receive the 'dwell' event...…**

I am logging the device coordinates and I can clearly see the accuracy being around 10 and yet, the dwell event is not being sent.

Update: I left the device on desk for like 40 mins. Got back, opened the app, started the geofence, and again, no dwell event being received and now there's not even the log event saying "Location dropped because in deep still mode"... I'm lost...

Update 2: Even after reinstalling the app it doesn't make the dwell nor the enter events to be received (I also added monitoring for 'enter')

Comment: have you figured it out what is this "deep still mode"? Same thing is happening to me

Comment: Nope. The API is hit and miss and you get some conclusions which could be very wrong

Answer (score 1):

### Note : Dwell event only occur if you are not already inside the geofence while registering, It will work if you walk inside the geofence after registratoin.

#### You can also try using fake gps to test this and keep on changing the location, worked for me all the time.

I have tried following solutions and both worked for me.

1st solution is same as your case, as you want to have only dwell event.

```
builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);

builder.setLoiteringDelay(500);
you also have to add this method(time in millis)
```

2nd solution is for who would like to have all three events 'ENTER','DWELL' & 'EXIT'

follow the code snippet

```
// Register your initial trigger with both 'ENTER' & 'DWELL' events
.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);

//and then set transition types for all three events

.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL |
 Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);


//dont forget to add the setLoiteringDelay, in millis

.setLoiteringDelay(5000);
```

Hope this will for you guys as well.
I can provide complete working solution if anyone needs it please do comment.